# How to convert XML to string in Perl

Tags: xml, string, perl, email

I need to send an XML file as the body of an email. I want to convert the XML to a simple string, put it into the body and then send the email. I remember I did that before in C# by loading the file as PlainText into a RichTextBox.

```
my $xmlfilename;
my $myxml;
# XML TO STRING?
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
header => [
To      => '"AB <a@b.it"',
From    => '"CD" <c@d.it>',
Subject => "TEST",
],
body => $myxml,
);
sendmail($email);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the XML data from the file, then it will be a "simple string". I'm not sure what the confusion is.

```
my $xmlfilename;

open my $fh, $xmlfilename or die "Can't open $xmlfilename: $!";

my $myxml = do { local $/; <$fh>; };

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        To      => '"AB <a@b.it"',
        From    => '"CD" <c@d.it>',
        Subject => "TEST",
    ],
    body => $myxml,
);

sendmail($email);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my $xmlfilename; 
my $myxml; 
open (FILE, '>', "$xmlfilename") or die "$!";
while (<FILE>){
    $myxml = "$myxml"."$_";  

 }
close (FILE);
my $email = Email::Simple->create( 
header => [ 
    To => '"AB <a@b.it"', 
    From => '"CD" <c@d.it>', 
    Subject => "TEST", 
], 
    body => $myxml, 
); 
    sendmail($email);
```

---

or if you want you can parse xml
with [http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Parser](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aParser) module